# Making one table with these two Queries

Tags: google-bigquery

Hi I am calculating CRentention and I want to calculate the retention for 1day, 3 day and 7 days, but I have made three queries, can somebody please tell me how I can write thee in one query. 
Please help!

Comment: Sample data to run this queries over with would help a lot!

Comment: I cannot add the data somehow but I edited it to give some idea, I basically have two tables and both start from different dates but I need to find the users who finished the tutorial and had sessions on their first day, on 3rd day of finishing the tutorial and also on 7th day. eg. 32 finished on 7/7/2007, 21 of them returned on 7/7/2007, only 12 of them return on 10/7/2007 and so on. and I need it by date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way to combine multiple queries is generally a join. If you take each of your queries and turn them into subqueries, then join by date, this should give you the results you want.

As in:

```
SELECT one_day.activity_date as activity_date,
    one_day.signed_up_users, one_day.logged_in_users, one_day.retention_pct,
    three_day.signed_up_users, three_day.logged_in_users, three_day.retention_pct,
    seven_day.signed_up_users, seven_day.logged_in_users, seven_day.retention_pct
FROM (SELECT ... ) as one_day
JOIN (SELECT ... ) as three_day
ON one_day.activity_date = three_day.activity_date
JOIN (SELECT ... ) as seven_day
ON one_day.activity_date = seven_day.activity_date
```

You also can use `IF()` clauses to do this in a non-joined fashion. You can create a column that is 1 if in the 1 day count and 0 otherwise, then compute the sum when you aggregate.